# Automatically changing toolbar title on activity change

Tags: android

I just migrated to toolbar in my navigation drawer app , now I just cant figure out that how to change the toolbar title according to the current on screen activity or navigation drawer item selected

Comment: you will be having different toolbar in diff. activity right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable action bar and use a header by taking a TextView in your each activity
Now you can set different title for your activities 
try this I hope it will work for you

```
ActivityName.mTitle.setText("Title 1");
```

or if you want to set the position of your navigation bar as title then use this

```
mTitle.setText(navMenuTitles[position]);
```

in your MainActivity

Comment: Thanx dev , it worked like a charm. Ive been digging since 3 days. Saved my day. :-)

Answer (score 0):

To change the action bar title based on NavigationDrawer option, use

```
getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
```

in

```
onDrawerOpened()
```

where `mDrawerTitle` can be `getTitle()` of your Activity.